# Traversing an array/class index by index to copy into another one

Tags: .net, vb.net

I can't find the exact term to search for, but need a way to copy all the elements of a class into another identical class.

For instance, another programmer has a class sort of like this that I have to support:

```
Class Person
    Public Rank AS Integer
    Public Salary As Single
    Public Age As Integer
End Class
```

So I write my code to handle it and copy  it to another class if required.

Then he adds:

```
Public Height As single
```

And

```
Public Weight As Single
```

And I have to update all my code.

What I think I'm remembering is some kind of syntax that does something like this:

```
For Each Element in Source
    Source.Element.Copy(Target, SizeOf(Element)
```

I know there is no such source, but that is the basic idea I am after and as close as I can come to remembering what I saw done before. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This question may lead to a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a base class which implements `ICloneable`:

```
Public Class BaseData
    Implements ICloneable

    Public Overridable Function Clone() As Object Implements ICloneable.Clone
        Dim cloned As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(Me.GetType())

        ' get all public properties
        Dim properties As IEnumerable(Of PropertyInfo) = Me.GetType().GetProperties()

        ' for each property...
        For Each prop In properties
            ' if this property is writable
            If prop.CanWrite Then
                ' get property value
                Dim val As Object = prop.GetValue(Me, Nothing)

                If TypeOf val Is ICloneable Then
                    ' clone the value
                    val = CType(val, ICloneable).Clone()
                ElseIf TypeOf val Is IList AndAlso val.GetType().IsGenericType Then
                    ' clone the list
                    Dim list As IList = Activator.CreateInstance(val.GetType())
                    For Each item In CType(val, IList)
                        If TypeOf item Is ICloneable Then
                            list.Add(CType(item, ICloneable).Clone())
                        Else
                            list.Add(item)
                        End If
                    Next
                    val = list
                End If

                ' assign to cloned
                prop.SetValue(cloned, val, Nothing)
            End If
        Next

        Return cloned
    End Function
End Class
```

Then I can get a copy of the object using:

```
Dim copy As Object = original.Clone()
```